# _CastError (type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast) [wlifecycle]

Tags: flutter, list, api, dictionary, casting

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
```

List currency = [];

Future getResponse(BuildContext context) async {
var url =
"http://api.navasan.tech/latest/?api_key=freeTFyHoFiXvgG6UNOlQHfehDasa7eK";
var value = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
developer.log(value.body, name: 'main');
developer.log('getResponse', name: 'wlifecycle');

```
if (currency.isEmpty) {
  if (value.statusCode == 200) {
    _showSnackBar(context, 'به روز رسانی با موفقیت انجام شد .');
    developer.log(value.body,
        name: 'getResponse', error: convert.jsonDecode(value.body));
    Map jsonList = convert.jsonDecode(value.body);
    if (jsonList.isNotEmpty) {
      jsonList.forEach((key, value) {
        setState(() {
          currency.add(Currency(
              id: jsonList[key],
              value: jsonList[key]["value"],
              change: jsonList[key]["change"],
              timestamp: jsonList[key]['timestamp'],
              date: jsonList[key]["date"]));
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
return value;
```

}

Comment: API : 
{
  "harat_naghdi_buy": {
    "value": "49970",
    "change": -720,
    "timestamp": 1678374494,
    "date": "1401-12-18 18:38:14"
  }, 
}

Model : 
// ignore: file_names
class Currency {
  String? id;
  int? value;
  int? change;
  int? timestamp;
  String? date;

  Currency(
      {required this.id,
      required this.value,
      required this.change,
      required this.timestamp,
      required this.date});
}

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the code in the `setState` to :

```
if (jsonList.isNotEmpty) {
  jsonList.forEach((key, value) {
    var currencyObj = Currency(
        id: key,
        value: value['value'],
        change: value['change'],
        timestamp: value['timestamp'],
        date: value['date']);
    setState(() {
      currency.add(currencyObj);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
line 71 > value: value['value],